# Does webpack-dev-server work with Material-UI components?

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI components (e.g. DropDownMenu, RadioButtonGroup) in my React app. When I run it under webpack-dev-server the components render, but I can't interact with them.

I'm running `injectTapEventPlugin()` as [recommended](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/installation).

However, if I build the app using webpack and then load it in the browser (tried Chrome and Edge), all is fine. I can interact with the Material-UI components as expected.

Am I missing something? Is there some kind of fix? webpack-dev-server's hot reload makes my life easier.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. Must have been something in my webpack configuration that was causing it.

I merged some settings from the [Material UI example configuration file](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui-webpack-example/blob/25938ac6f5db94645e6ea9f24a903792d3133c5d/webpack-dev-server.config.js) into my existing file and it starting working.

Not entirely sure what was causing it, but happy to have it fixed.